# The argument "value" is required during Terratest execution

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terratest

I do have a terraform submodule with the following code

```
resource "aws_ec2_tags" "set_tags" {
   for_each = var.tags
   resource_id = var.resource
   key = each.key
   value = each.value
}
```

During normal terraform execution, it works as expected. But during terratest `go test`, it emits `The argument "value" is required, but no definition was found`. I added test values via `terraform.Options` and as default value but it still emits the same error.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include your Terratest code as well?

Comment: We would definitely need to see the Terratest code to answer this question. Thanks.

Comment: As others have said, it's impossible to say for certain what's going on here without seeing how you're running Terraform in both the working an non-working cases, but it might be helpful to know that Terraform considers the value `null` to be equivalent to omitting a value, and so it seems like in your failing case there is an element of `var.tags` whose value is `null` rather than being set to a valid string.

Comment: I'm getting this error during normal terraform execution.